# Attendance Time in and Time out Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like get help in the following Data , we have hand punch machines which saves exit and entry log , each exit and entry log stores a different row for an employee id

```
EMP ID |  EntryTime                | ExitTime
11769     2015-02-01 08:00:00        NULL
11769     NULL                       2015-02-01 13:00:00
```

Basically every two entry for in and out.

I would like to get the time in and time out for a single day . As you can see this is the time in and time out for a day , but it stores two records .
So in this regard I am quite confused how to tackle this. also would like to calculate the hours worked

A help would be very much appreciated

Comment: What happens when the times are mismatched?

Comment: I just wanted to get the first in and last out of that day of a particular employee.. times are not mismatched .. a employee can have multiple outs and multiple ins

Comment: all i want the first in and last exit out ... thats all and on that basis i want to calculate the hours worked.. i am kind of confused right now .. a little help would be much appreciated .. I am newbie

Comment: Do one thing. Use CASE to determine which is the entry and out time. For example, SELECT MAX(Time), MIN(Time) and then with CASE, get the entry and out time comparison as I am sure there is an entry and out time. Just compare them in the case. Right now, this would work,

Comment: let me check thanks by the way i will update

Comment: If you want the **first** in and the **last** out you should say so in your question text, update your sample data so you have more than one in/out on the same day, and give the actual expected result in your text.

Comment: And as is clear from the Q&A taking place in the comments you should also tell what other conditions are met (or not), like: can there be missing start/end times, can someone clock in on day X and clock out on X+1, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a subquery in such cases.

```
 SELECT at1.empId ,at1.EntryTime ,
        (SELECT    MIN(a2.ExitTime)
          FROM      attendance at2
          WHERE     at1.empId = at2.empId
                    AND  at2.ExitTime >at1.EntryTime ) ExitTime
FROM    attendance at1
WHERE   at1.EntryTime IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: its returning the duplicate records as well

Comment: this is because i am joining it with another table now where the employe names and designation are stored .. your query worked as a charm ,, the thing is that employee record has two hand impression stored in the table . which resulted in two rows from that table.. Inner join is not working not even the left join

Comment: Why do you need the DISTINCT?

Comment: @Salis That join with another table is a separate issue that is not within the scope of your question. **Do not change the goal posts during the game**

Comment: @Salis Younsi : great . Then there is no need of DISTINCT clause over here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Case and MIN and MAX to get the first in and last out. Then use dateDiff function to get the number of hours/mins

Comment: Can you publish your query

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is exactly in the sample you provided, and you don't have back to back swipes (such as an employee might swipe his card twice thinking first one is not committed) then you can do a query like this:

```
WITH InOut (empId, EntryTime, ExitTime) as
(SELECT  empId ,
        a1.EntryTime ,
        ( SELECT    MIN(a2.ExitTime)
          FROM      attendance a2
          WHERE     a1.empId = a2.empId
                    AND a1.EntryTime < a2.ExitTime
        )
FROM    attendance a1
WHERE   EntryTime IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT empId ,
       EntryTime ,
       ExitTime,
       DATEDIFF(Minute, EntryTime, ExitTime) AS minutes FROM InOut;
```

EDIT:
I don't understand your comment. Here is a full sample:

```
DECLARE @attendance TABLE
    (
      EMPID INT ,
      EntryTime DATETIME NULL ,
      ExitTime DATETIME NULL
    );

INSERT  @attendance
        ( EMPID, EntryTime, ExitTime )
VALUES  ( 11769, '2015-02-01 08:00:00', NULL ),
        ( 11769, NULL, '2015-02-01 13:00:00' ),
        ( 11769, '2015-02-02 09:00:00', NULL ),
        ( 11769, NULL, '2015-02-02 12:00:00' ),
        ( 11769, '2015-02-03 08:00:00', NULL ),
        ( 11769, NULL, '2015-02-03 13:00:00' ),
        ( 1, '2015-02-01 08:10:00', NULL ),
        ( 1, NULL, '2015-02-01 13:10:00' ),
        ( 1, '2015-02-02 09:10:00', NULL ),
        ( 1, NULL, '2015-02-02 12:10:00' ),
        ( 1, '2015-02-03 08:10:00', NULL ),
        ( 1, NULL, '2015-02-03 13:10:00' ),
        ( 2, '2015-02-01 08:30:00', NULL ),
        ( 2, NULL, '2015-02-01 13:30:00' ),
        ( 2, '2015-02-02 09:30:00', NULL ),
        ( 2, NULL, '2015-02-02 12:30:00' ),
        ( 2, '2015-02-03 08:30:00', NULL );

WITH    InOut ( empId, EntryTime, ExitTime )
          AS ( SELECT   EMPID ,
                        a1.EntryTime ,
                        ( SELECT    MIN(a2.ExitTime)
                          FROM      @attendance a2
                          WHERE     a1.EMPID = a2.EMPID
                                    AND a1.EntryTime < a2.ExitTime
                        )
               FROM     @attendance a1
               WHERE    EntryTime IS NOT NULL
             )
    SELECT  empId ,
            EntryTime ,
            ExitTime ,
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EntryTime, ExitTime) AS minutes
    FROM    InOut;
```

and the result is:

```
empId   EntryTime               ExitTime                minutes
11769   2015-02-01 08:00:00.000 2015-02-01 13:00:00.000 300
11769   2015-02-02 09:00:00.000 2015-02-02 12:00:00.000 180
11769   2015-02-03 08:00:00.000 2015-02-03 13:00:00.000 300
1       2015-02-01 08:10:00.000 2015-02-01 13:10:00.000 300
1       2015-02-02 09:10:00.000 2015-02-02 12:10:00.000 180
1       2015-02-03 08:10:00.000 2015-02-03 13:10:00.000 300
2       2015-02-01 08:30:00.000 2015-02-01 13:30:00.000 300
2       2015-02-02 09:30:00.000 2015-02-02 12:30:00.000 180
2       2015-02-03 08:30:00.000 NULL                    NULL
```

Comment: it does not return the result as expected ..it should give the exact time in and time out for the same day but it doesnot

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using? I wouldn't assume a very old version, if you are using an old version you should include it in your question.